# (HTML / CSS ) Bootstrap DIV outside on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

so my problem is that on my current website (galacticempire-forum.de/hubit_website[it's just for testing purposes on there]) the DIV where my skills are listed is half outside the screen when I open it on my mobile phone. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djzvz.jpg)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

MY HTML Code:  pastebin.com/sY9epmvM

My CSS Code: pastebin.com/Cq9sX3Uu

Cheers Hubit

PS: I used Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Post your html/css code

Comment: HTML: http://pastebin.com/sY9epmvM        CSS: http://pastebin.com/Cq9sX3Uu

Comment: @Vel meant you should edit it into your question, not just post links

Comment: @loki I can't fit the whole code in there.

Comment: Then try to come up with a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete these 3 inline styles:

```
margin-left: 1800px;
```

and

```
margin-left: 740px; margin-right: 700px;
```

Is that the layout you wanted?

[image]

Comment: Yup thanks. I just have to figure out how to repeat the city in the bottom.